# request.accept_language is always null in python

Tags: python, pylons

In pylons project when I do request.accept_language.best_matches(), it is returning me Null. I have set 2 languages in browser (en-us and es-ar) by going to Preferences-Content- Languages in firefox.

How can I get the languages specified in the browser?

`repr(request.accept_language)` gives `<NilAccept: <class 'webob.acceptparse.Accept'>>`

Comment: what is `repr(request.accept_language)`?

Comment: request is http request object, accept_language is one of the parameters in the http request. I get null only for this parameter, not for others like host,accept etc.

Comment: @user1515754 Read JF Sebastian's question again: he wants to know the repr of the object, not a general description of what you believe the api to be.

Comment: Sry.. the repr gives "<NilAccept: <class 'webob.acceptparse.Accept'>>"

Comment: @user1515754 Please put that in your question, and formatted appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at `request.headers['accept-language']`, or indeed the entire `request.headers` object. I suspect your browser is not providing those headers.

Also, take a look at the browser request in wireshark, and the client request on the server.

Comment: You are right, request.headers object does not have Accept Language. I have verified the http header using "Live Http Headers". This gives the header as below.  
GET /concept/** HTTP/1.1

Host: intern1.**.in

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language: en,en-us;q=0.8,es;q=0.5,es-ar;q=0.3

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate


Do you know how to come over this? or get the full header information in request.header

Comment: @user1515754 check what the server is receiving with tcpdump or something. The header may be getting yanked by some proxy or something, or perhaps it's getting pulled out by the web server.

Comment: i checked using the tcpdump and wireshark. It is getting Accept-Language in http GET request.

Comment: @user1515754 bug in pylons then, maybe.

Comment: @ Colin Dunklau, No, pylons sample project is returning me the correct values. But in my actual project, it is not returning.
You are absolutely right that some proxy is stripping off this value. How to debug that do u have any idea?
Thanks a lot for your help.